# Failed emulator dependency

Tags: android, android-studio, android-10.0

I'm trying to install the version 7 of system image for Android Q. It should be the beta 6. When I try to update in Android studio I receive an error saying emulator 29.1.7 not found but I can't see any update for the emulator. What I have to do? I'm using Android studio 3.4.2

Comment: Most likely, you have to wait until Google gets a grip. I ran into this error as well, and I ran into a similar one earlier in the Q release cycle. [This issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139139804) appears to be for this problem. My guess is that the problem will not get fixed until Android Studio 3.5 ships in stable form.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks, I was trying other versions but I read it's not enough, so I will wait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android emulator 29.1.7 is not yet a stable version, therefore Android Studio does not show you this upgrade if you check for updates from the *Stable Channel*. The update is however available on the non-stable *Canary Channel*.

If you are fine with running a non-stable version of the emulator, then you can install it as follows:

- Open the Settings dialog (`File > Settings`)
- Go to `Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Updates`
- Change to the *Canary Channel* in the dropdown box
- Click OK.

Then:

- Open the SDK manager (`Tools > SDK Manager`)
- Click the SDK Tools tab
- Check the Android Emulator checkbox to have it updated to the latest release (which now should be > 29.1.7).
- Click Apply.

After the installation is done, switch back to the 'Stable Channel' in the updates settings, and check for new updates. The (stable) Android Q update should now run without issues.